# Ask for permission from facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing login with facebook on my android app, but i need to get birthday and location.However to do so, I have to submit on my facebook developer account notes.I couldnt get the notes rightly so. They are telling me that I must show:How a person logs in with Facebook and How a person sees this permission used in your app. But how do I request the permission?And what screencast I am going to upload? As I know once facebook page opens, user just sees my app is requesting public profile, email permissions.Do I have to do some popup or what?

> ```
>       LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(MainActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile","user_location","email", "user_birthday", "contact_email"));
> ```

Comment: Login with your developer account and take screenshots of each step.Your developer account has all the permissions by default without review.

Comment: but i dont have a page where am asking for permission, when user clicks login with facebook it shows facebook activity my app will recieve your email address.It doesnt show lcoation or birthday, its something controlled by facebook not me.Shall I in my app implement a popup where i ask for permission?

Comment: No you may not need to implement popups.But by default it should ask for this permissions. Read through this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions . "contact_email" is not a valid permission, get rid of it.

Comment: Also you are calling this on `onActivityResult` right ?  `mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(request, result, data);`